# Can the initial item of a QComboBox display a shorter text item than in the item list?

Tags: qt, qt5, qcombobox

I have a QComboBox with a long label.

```
qc = new QComboBox;
qc->addItem(tr("LabelA is a very long label here."));
```

The text in the dropdown is much wider than I would like, yet I want the long text string when the combobox is in it's dropped down state showing the list of items.

Is there a way to make the dropdown appear with a short text item when not activated and only once it has been clicked (showing it's item list) does the dropdown display the entire text at full width?

So when viewing the QComboBox before being activated, it might show something like ...

```
MyLabel: LabelA
```

Note: the rest of the text " is a very long label here." is not being displayed.

I did see some similar questions, but the answers were left unchecked and didn't appear to work.

Comment: If we set QComboBox text after clicking and handle ComboBox with indexes, is it work for you?

Comment: Not sure I'm quite understanding what you're suggesting, but I'll try to research it.

Comment: I searched about it, Not possible. you have to do it manually. use signals to change text, or maybe make a new class and inherit from QComboBox and do that inside inherited class.

Comment: You could set different widths for the combobox and dropdown, if that would be enough... Via CSS for example: `QComboBox QAbstractItemView { min-width: XYZ; }`

Comment: Ok, I'll give these a try and eventually report back with what I find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets solve this problem step by step covering wider scope

**Step 1 :** Dropdown width should be equal to the item having maximum length. (we will use QFontMetrics to find the width of item having maximum length in pixels).

**step 2 :** To Find the item having maximum length,insert items in QStringList and iterate over each item to find the item having maximum length.

```
QFont myFont("times", 10); //assuming you are using times new roman
QFontMetrics fm(myFont);
int pixelwide; // stores the length in pixes
int maxLen = 0 ;
QStringList itemList;
QString maxDropdownLen,styleSheet;
itemList<<"LabelA is a very long label here.";

for(int i=0; i<itemList.size();i++){
    pixelwide = fm.width(itemList[i]); //get the width in pixels
    if(pixelwide>maxLen)
          {
             maxLen=pixelwide; //setting maximum width in pixels
          }
    }
```

**step 3:** Now set the dropdown width to the width of the item having maximum length.

```
maxDropdownLen = QString::number(pixelwide);
styleSheet = "QComboBox QAbstractItemView { min-width: %1;}";
qc->addItems(itemList);
qc->setStyleSheet(styleSheet.arg(maxDropdownLen));
```

[image]
  [image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I plugged it in pretty quickly but it didn't work. Likely because my QComboBox is buried in a layout->group->layout->widget->layout ... I'll have to play around with it for a bit.